# Getting Viber message history on PC

Tags: viber

I am new to Viber and I have followig issue:
There is some account accessed from phone .The phone(including number)  was changed and SIM from the old one is not accessable.
Is there possible to get Viber message history on PC(Windows) for the account connected to the old phone ? What are the steps  ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have already installed and authenticated Viber on PC?

Comment: Yes , installed

Comment: Is it authenticated with old phone version?